# How to redirect to a sub directory in react using react router?

Tags: php, html, reactjs, wordpress, react-router

I have a react application installed at root domain suppose domain.com and I have installed Wordpress in a sub directory named domain.com/blog. If I add empty route like `<Route exact path="/blog" />` , I get a blank page.
Is there a way to access .php or .html files in a sub directory outside of the react components?

Please refer the routing code below

```
    <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Index {...props} />} />
    
              {/*route added since /blog redirects to / because of 404 condition at the bottom */}
              {/* <Route exact path="/blog" /> */}
    
              {/*404 redirection for other URLs */}
              <Redirect to="/" />
              <Redirect from="/" to="/" />
            </Switch>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Because of the Redirects added below if I don't provide a route for /blog it redirects to root '/' URL (This is the 404 page not found condition).

Answer (score 0):

Route is only for react's inside routing. If you want to route some other platforms url you need to use anchor(a tag)

You can read more here [this](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

```
<a href="https://example.com/blog">Go to Blog</a>
```

Update:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Index {...props} />} />

          <Route path="*" render={props => <NotFound />}
        </Switch>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I understand what you said, but I have to provide a route for blog url since I have added a 404 redirect so that every other routes will be redirected to a 404 component. Is there a way to get the 404 route and direct a custom route to a sub directory

Comment: Route is only require for react's inside routing. You dont need to add any route for other web url. For other url you need to add a tag not the Link. Link will only use for react's inside url.

Comment: I get it! but I'm using the 404 redirect route `<Redirect to="/" />` , because of this if I write domain.com/blog its getting redirected to homepage. This stops only if I provide a route specifically for blog. Is there any other way of redirecting it to domain and also achieving 404 redirects?

Comment: please share your code. And another way it could be. Open the blog in new tab and your react site will redirect to home.